# Redireccionar artículos pero NO imagenes

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirección

Tengo un blog al que he pasado de enlaces tipo 
`http://www.dominio.net/2015/03/noticia` a `http://www.dominio.net/noticia`
He añadido lo siguiente en el fichero .htaccess

`RedirectMatch 301 /([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ http://www.dominio.net/$3`

hasta aquí bien, mi sorpresa es que tambén afecta a las imagenes que están por ejemplo en: `http://www.dominio.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Foto.jpg`

¿Qué tendría que hacer para que no afecte a las imagenes la redirección?

Comment: habría que agregarle el `^` para que sea "si empieza con", onda `^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$`

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$ [NC]

Comment: @aloMalbarez solucionado! tan fácil y tan difícil :)

Comment: @Bryro gracias por la respuesta.